# Java Spring Boot - pass dropdown option selection to method by button click

Tags: java, spring-boot, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown which consists of options retrieved from a method. The user should be able to select one of these options, and press a submit button. Upon pressing the submit button, the button executes a method that takes the selected option and stores it in some other variable.

In fact, the value of the options are objects from a List, thus upon pressing the submit button, the object will be stored in a "current object is:" variable.

Using Spring Boot, how to I set up the requestmapping etc. to fulfill this? Some code below:

```
@MultipartConfig
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/Teacher", produces = "text/html;charset=UTF-8")
public class Teacher {
    TestController testcont = TestController.getInstance();

    @GetMapping("")
    @ResponseBody

    public String homePage(@RequestParam(value = "file", required = false) String name, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.append("<p><a>Current Test for students:</a>\n"

                + "<form>"
                + "<button type='submit onClick='/sendTest'>Send Test</button>"
                + "<button type='reset' onClick='/resetTest'>Clear Test</button>"

                + "<fieldset><p>"
                + "<label>Select test</label>"
                + "<select id = 'myList'>"
                + currentTestOptions() // input
                + "</select></p></fieldset>"
                + "</form>"
                + "</p>");
```

...Below are two methods: 1st is what the button should do, incomplete at the moment, 2nd is method that returns selection options...

```
@PostMapping
    @RequestMapping("/sendTest")
    @ResponseBody
    public void sendTest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException{

        Part selection = request.getPart("id");
        System.out.println(selection.getName());

    }


    public String currentTestOptions() {


        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for(Test test : testcont.showAllTests()){
            sb.append("<option value = '" + test + "'>" + test.getName() + " - " + test.getFile().getName() + "</option>");
        }

        return sb.toString();

    }
```

EDIT for clearer code format:

My drop-down form looks like this currenty:

```
sb.append("<p>"
                + "<div style='height:200px;width:500px;border:1px solid #ccc;font:16px/26px Georgia, Garamond, Serif;overflow:auto;'>"

                + "<form action='/Teacher' method='get'>"

                + "<input type='submit' value='Submit' action='/sendTest' method='post'>"

                + "<input type='submit' value='Reset' action='/resetCurrentTest' method='post'>"

                + "<a>Current Test for students: " + testcont.getActiveTest() + "</a>"

                + "<fieldset><p>"
                + "<label>Select test</label>"
                + "<select id = 'selection'>"
                + currentTestOptions() // input
                + "</select></p></fieldset>"
                + "</form>"
                + "</div>"
                + "</p>");
```

and the method the

```
"<input type='submit' value='Submit' action='/sendTest' method='post'>"
```

button should execute is:

```
@PostMapping("/sendTest")
    @ResponseBody
    public void sendTest(@RequestParam(value = "selection") HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
                    throws IOException, ServletException{

        for(Test test : testcont.showAllTests()){
            if(test.getName().equals("selection")){
                testcont.SetActiveTest(test);
                System.out.println(testcont.getActiveTest());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't need to "pass" anything. If the `<select>` is a child of the form, its value will be included in the form submission. Give it a `name` attribute.

Comment: Also, there are much better ways to perform HTML templating than string concatenation

Comment: Yeah, we're switching to Thymeleaf on monday after we read up on it over the weekend, currently it's just quick prototyping work :)

Thanks for the tip! Also, how do I handle the selection with request, so that I can set the storage attribute as the selection?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question

Comment: No probs, let me rephrase it:

The drop-down menu options are objects retrieved from a List. When the user selects the wanted option, the selection is used as a parameter for the button's corresponding method. What the button does, is take the selected option from the drop-down, and stores it in a seperate value.

Usually with text inputs, you can do something like: 
String selection = request.getParameter("textInput")

What would be the corresponding way to store an object using http request? Or any other way?

Comment: You shouldn't need a function. Set a target and method on the form and the request will be built automatically.

Comment: so I guess the reference to the method should be in the form's action='method'?

Comment: Thanks! This is what I need to execute when the "submit" is pressed

`public void sendTest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException{
  
  for(Test test : testcont.showAllTests()){
   if(test.getName().equals(request.getParameter("value"))){
    testcont.SetActiveTest(test);
   }
  }
  
 }`

Comment: Yes, use the same mapping in Spring and the form target. There is no need for `getParameter`, you can use `@RequestParam`, the same as you have for the home page.

Comment: `<form target="/sendTest" method="post">`

Comment: Updated main post for clearer format :)